# Error in arduino ide

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i am sonny..i am currently working on arduino and with that i am trying to install ROS. While i am trying to run my first basic code on arduino with ROS, the Hello world code in the ros_lib, i am getting an error like below..
In file included from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:31,
from /home/traininghes/arduino-1.5.2/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:38,
from HelloWorld.pde:6:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/forwards.h:37: fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
i am unable to verify the code since i don't understand the error.
It will be appreciated if someone please look at this issue and help me to get out of this problem.

Thanks..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140186/error-in-arduino-ide/) by [sonny](https://answers.ros.org/users/13381/sonny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess would be that you miss the boost library. on your computer. The message states that the compiler is not able to find shared_ptr.hpp in the boost library.

You should check that the boost library is installed on you computer. I think you can use that command in the terminal to see :

```
apt-cache pkgnames | grep boost
```

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonny](https://answers.ros.org/users/13381/sonny/) on 2014-03-18**:
but when i check the boost directory in usr/include/boost, that file shared_ptr.hpp is present there..still i am not able to resolve the error.

please help
Now i am getting  new error like below;
fatal error: ros.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

ros.h is already include in the ros library along with where the arduino ide is stored, then why not i is picking it up.
please help

thanks